# Issue with charset and data

Tags: php, mysql

I try to explain the whole problem with my poor english:

I use to save data from my application (encoded on utf8) to database using the default connection of `PHP` (`latin1`) to the tables of my DB with `latin1` as charset.

That wasn't a big problem : for example the string `Magnüs` was stored as `MagnÃƒÂ¼s`, and when I recovered the data I saw correctly the string `Magnüs` (because the default connection, `latin1`).

Now, I change the connection, using the correct charset, with `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $mydb)`, and I've also changed the charset of my tables's fields, so the value now is correctly store as `Magnüs` on DB; Then I still seeing `Magnüs` when I retrieve the data and I print on my Web Application.

Of course, unfortunatly, some old values now are badly printed (`MagnÃƒÂ¼s` is printed as `MagnÃƒÂ¼s`).

What I'd like to do is "to convert" these old values with the real encoding.

`ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;` will convert only the field type, not the data.

So, a solution (discovered on internet) should be this:

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE field field BLOB;
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE field field VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

But these old string won't change on database, so neither in the Web Application when I print them.

Why? And what can I do?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like your characters are "wrong", just that they're being rendered according to the wrong charset wherever you're viewing them. There are the actual bytes stored in the table and then there's the scheme according to which they are displayed. Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Yeah, i "wrong" terminology :) Sorry

Comment: @markzzz - Where are you viewing the data that it appears wrong?

Comment: Uhm, on HeidiSql, watching the tables. And on my web application:)

Comment: So this problem can't be resolved? Unbelievable... :)

Comment: P.S. Magnüs is stored as MagnÃƒÂ¼s because the old charset was latin1, is not a view problem, is that word stored in that manner....

Comment: @markzzz - I am not all that familiar with `CHARACTER SET` but I am almost certain you're wrong and this *is* a view problem. It looks to me like `CHARACTER SET` changes how the DB *interprets* the contents of a field (e.g. when doing comparisons); it does not change what bytes are stored in the column. As I said before `ÃƒÂ¼` and `ü` are two different ways to render the *exact same bytes*. In other words, the correct bytes were stored in the table. You almost certainly do not need a conversion of the data.

Comment: NO! I need! Because now, changing my application and storing the correct data (with `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $mydb)`) I see the old strings (as `MagnÃƒÂ¼s`) wrong :)

Comment: I wrote the problem better. Hope is more clear right now :)

Comment: I had a table where the foreign characters had been corrupted inside the database. The only way around was to fix the UTF-8 character set on the table, and then run SQL update queries like `UPDATE tablename SET `fieldname` = REPLACE(`field_name`, '§', 'S');` (where the § represents the special character(s) and the 'S' represents it's correct replacement.

Comment: I think I've resolved : just convert back the table on latin1; than apply those 2 queries of ALTER TABLE, and the data will be encoded correctly on UTF8. Magical?:)

Comment: Really, not sure because this works (in some fields I need to to this "back to latin1" and "execute those 2 query" 2-3 times : after the chars is encoded correctly. So strange, but it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your forms are sending UTF-8 encoded text, and that the text in your table is also UTF-8 encoded.

According to the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html#id749852), the last two ALTER you mentioned do not change the column contents encoding, its more like a "reinterpretation" of the contents.

> Warning
>   The CONVERT TO operation converts column values between the character sets. This is not  what you want if you have a column in one character set (like latin1) but the stored values actually use some other, incompatible character set (like utf8). In this case, you have to do the following for each such column:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

> The reason this works is that there is no conversion when you convert to or from BLOB columns.